# Java won't connect to my database

Tags: java, sql, ms-access, jdbc

Here's my code:

```
import java.sql.*;

public class DBConnector {
private static Connection conn;

public static void connectToDB()
{
//load the driver
try
{
Class.forName ("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
System.out.println ("Driver successfully loaded");
}
catch (ClassNotFoundException c)
{
System.out.println ("Unable to load database driver");
}

//connect to the database
try
{
String filename = "TopYouTubeVideos.mdb"; 
String database = "jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ=";
database += filename.trim () + ";DriverID=22;READONLY=true}";
conn = DriverManager.getConnection (database, "", "");
System.out.println ("Connection database successfully established");
}
catch (Exception e)
{
System.out.println ("Unable to connect to the database");
}

}
```

The output is:

Driver successfully loaded

Unable to connect to the database

This has worked on a different computer than mine, connecting to the database through exactly the same code... does anyone have any idea why?

Thanks in advance :)

EDIT: I'm running Access 2007, Windows 7 64bit
By checking for the error, I get: java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified

From a little bit of research it seems this is a problem with my 'data source name'. I put my database file in the project folder, and the name is correct. Why is it not finding it?

EDIT: No, the database was the same on both computers. In the same folder as well.

EDIT: I think I may need to create a system dsm. Following the instructions on the internet dosent work though, because I  dont have the same files as them..

EDIT: I've tried to install that but it hasn't made a difference. My version of access is 64 bit alongside my version of netbeans..

Comment: Is the computer Operating System you got the fail Windows?

Comment: You must print the exception stacktrace instead of just printing a text message, try `e.printStackTrace()` to see what's going on...

Comment: Do you use different database systems on the two computers? The String for the DriverManager.getConnection() is not always the same dependeing on the database system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try installing a database engine + JVM that are both running in the same archeticture (i.e. 32bit), otherwise, you would receive a mismatch exception. I assume your JVM is 64bit but your database engine is not, so try installing a 64bit engine from the following link:
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255